# Application is Opening When Widget is pressed in PIXEL 2 (Android Q)

Tags: android-studio, android-10.0

I am having a widget for my application and it requires permission to start using it else I have displayed a toast message to the user. I have tested in all devices everything is working fine except in PIXEL 2.

When I click the Widget it opens the application after toasting the message only in PIXEL 2.

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

```
 @Override
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(context, requiredPermissionsRecording)) {
            updateWidget(context, manager, isRecording);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.widget_toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```